# ASP.net MVC oAuth and Facebook javascript SDK

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth

This question is a bit long-winded but I'm sure that the answer would help a lot of people. I just can't find the guidance I need anywhere.

I have created an ASP.net MVC 4 web application using the out-of-the box project template in Visual Studio 2012. It instantly gives you a website that allows users to sign-up and authenticate with their Facebook credentials using oAuth. So far so good.

My application uses the Facebook Javascript SDK and OpenGraph to carry out actions on behalf of the user. That's also working fine.

Here is the scenario I have a problem with:-

1. A user (John) signs-up using his FB profile
2. John logs in to my application using his Facebook login. He was already logged into Facebook so he didn't need to re-enter his login credentials.
3. John leaves the browser open and doesn't log out of my application
4. John's wife (Jane) opens up a new tab, goes to the Facebook site, logs John out of Facebook and logs in using her own Facebook credentials. She also leaves the browser open when she is done.
5. John returns and continues to use my application from where he left it. Assuming that his session hasn't expired, he is still authenticated in my application as John but if the application makes any calls or carries out any actions using the javascript SDK it's as the logged in Facebook user, which is now Jane. Assuming they have both authorised my app (because they both have an account with my app) this happens silently and John's actions post to Jane's Facebook account.

I'm calling FB.getLoginStatus on every page that I use FB.api but that doesn't detect the change of user. I've tried storing and comparing response.authResponse.accessToken but this doesn't change when the user changes.

Can anybody offer some guidance on how to handle a change of Facebook user so that my application detects the FB user has changed and redirects them to the login page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm handling this by storing the FB userid at login and comparing that to the userid in the response object of FB.getLoginStatus on every page load. If they don't match I force a logout.